# Problems with android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to work through a tutorial on **android compose**. It works well while I use:kotlin-gradle-plugin:**1.5.31**, but the android studio has updated to :kotlin-gradle-plugin:**1.6.10**, and when I try running the program again it doesn't compile. I don't understand what the problem is. but even in the original run with the old version, I get the following message:

w: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:
-XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes
This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!

*when I try the new version it tells me that I must *migrate the code*, but when I do this I get the following message:*

e: This version (1.0.5) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.31 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.10 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 10s
  25 actionable tasks: 23 executed, 2 up-to-date

*and you can't migrate back even if you want to.*

I don't know what to do with this or how to proceed forward.

Comment: The current compose version 1.0 supports only 1.5.31.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find out that the right **compos version** for kotlin 1.6.10 is **1.2.0-alpha01**, but I still get the message that this is not a stable version and should not be production use. But at least my program runs again.

Comment: and once again the compos version has been updated to 1.2.0-alpha03.

Comment: 1.1.0 is a stable version. So I think going with the stable version is a good choice.

Comment: Because of the fact that Compose is still relatively new, what is stable today may not be so stable tomorrow, don't get to attached to one version.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, Figure out and fix the issue to run **compose version**

Currently Stable version 1.1.0

So here is my code for **build.gradle(Project:app)**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0'
    }

    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dreammeanings"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i specified `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` for `composeOptions` in `build.gradle` of the `app` module and error fixed:

**build.gradle(app)**

```
android {
   composeOptions { kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "your compose version"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the version of Compose and Kotlin.
A few days ago, I encountered a similar error, and after updating the Kotlin and Compose versions, my problem was fixed.

First of all change composeOptions:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    //kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.31'  the old version 
    kotlinCompilerVersion '1.6.21'
}
```

then update all your dependencies versions

```
dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    
    .
    .
    .
}
```

then add this classpaths to gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
  
    //the older version of kotlin
    //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
  
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
    
    .
    .
    .
```

}

At the end, i think this is an version compatibility issue between Kotlin and compose libraries.

You just need to update your dependencies.

> Note : the $compose_version that i used in the dependencies is an variable in buildscript

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.6.21"
        //compose_version = '1.0.5'
        compose_version = '1.2.0-rc01'
     }
     .
     .
     .
}
```

I hope it helps you to solve your problem.